# Anatomically Correct Winged Kappa

Tags: fantasy-races, anatomy, anatomically-correct

The Winged Kappa, or Hane No Haeta Kappa, is a type of Kappa with Wings

They have a mixture of avian and chelonian features. They have a pointed beak like a bird, with the eyes and nostrils high up like a turtle. Their neck is long and flexible, and can stretch in and out. Their torso is shelled like a turtle, but with a chest like that of birds and other such animals. They have avian wings in place of arms, and their legs have taloned feet. Their tail is like that of birds. Their head, shell, wings, and tail are covered in something between fur and feathers, whereas the chest, belly, and legs are scaly. The neck is bare with ring-shaped ridges around

They are capable of flying, walking upright, or swimming through water

How could such a winged kappa fit together internally, to allow all of these features?

Comment: [Is this creature you're talking about](https://yokai.com/hanenohaetakappa/)? For anatomically correct folklore creatures which are not much much known (kappas are famous enough. But winged ones... A bit less :p), it could be interesting to give a reference link so that people don't get lost ^^.

Comment: -1 for making me look the creature up. You need to add sufficient links and details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few areas of the body which seem to present the most problems. Besides these parts, normal tetrapodal anatomy can easily be used

## Neck

An extending neck seems like a difficult anatomy to work with. Firstly, it will need to be empty of any skeletal elements, as such organs are inelastic. A plausible structure could be something like that of an octopus' tentacles: These structures are strong, yet flexible enough to extend enough for this kappa. The spinal cord and oesophagus/trachea would run down a cavity in the middle of the neck, with the trachea being supported by a very large number of cartilaginous rings. This ensures that the trachea stays open even when fully extended

## Chest

The mixture of different parts is most notable with the anatomy of the chest. Because of the shell, the wings will have to be mounted low on the body, which is not good for a flying animal. The main issue is with muscle attachments, but it seems this issue could be solved: Including a large keel will substantially increase area for muscle attachment. And, if you consider bats, it seems reasonable to say that this anatomy could have enough power for true flight

Answer (score 0):

## Archaeoptyrex

[image]

They have a mixture of avian and chelonian features. **check**

They have a pointed beak like a bird. **not check. But some dinosaurs do indeed have a beak.**

[image]

with the eyes and nostrils high up like a turtle. **check**

Their neck is long and flexible **check**

and can stretch in and out. **not check**

Their torso is shelled like a turtle **not check. But some dinosaurs have an armored body.**

[image]

but with a chest like that of birds and other such animals. **check**

They have avian wings in place of arms, and their legs have taloned feet. Their tail is like that of birds. **check.**

Their head, shell, wings, and tail are covered in something between fur **not check**

and feathers **check**

whereas the chest, belly, and legs are scaly. **check**

The neck is bare with ring-shaped ridges around **does not sound like a stretch**

[image]

They are capable of flying, walking upright **check**

or swimming through water. **not check. Though some dinosaurs can fly, swim and walk.**

[image]

Comment: Dinosaurs are archosaurs, not turtles

Comment: @IchthysKing You cannot put this imaginary animal in both clades at once. I suggest you choose one or fewer clades and move on.